# Need help with Segmented Control

Tags: cocoa-touch

I need help with the segmented control. I have put it in my window, and when I test run it, it is clickable. The only problem is I don't know how or where to code it so it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fire an action on new segment click, override `-(void)segmentAction:sender:`

```
- (void)segmentAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Segment %d selected", [sender selectedSegmentIndex]);
}
```

Can you be a little more specific what do you want to do?

Comment: yeah, sorry. Right now I have a utility page with an info button. On the main screen, I want to have a segment control so the main screen can be split up to about 3 screens, but still have that info button. Also, can you tell me not just the code, but where it goes? Thanks

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand what you are trying to do. UISegmentedControl, as I see it, is a horizontal container for segments that function as buttons, and I get the impression you want to use it for something else. As where the code goes, you must have UIViewController for your utility page or your segment control, I would suggest that you put the controlling code there. For example, see the tutorial UICatalog project in the ADC's iPhone section.

Comment: Isn't the Segment Control meant for being able to have like two different pages in one?

Comment: perhaps you're thinking of a Tab Bar?

Comment: I don't know maybe. Here Ill show you what I'm thinking of. Download a free app called BioMetricks Lite and press the info button. On the bottom of that page there is a bar that says Full Version, About, and Help. This is exactly what I want.